# Live update MySQL Data

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have the following code and it works great, I just want to convert it to live so it updates every 10 seconds or so without a page refresh, I'm guessing I'll need to use AJAX or Jquery but I lack the knowledge on how to do so.

```
=====VIA <?php include("database.php"); ?>====
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("ip/host","user","pass","db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>

====ON THE PAGE====
<? php

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM sql347511.1 ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<div class='infobox_data'>Temperature: ".$row['TEMP']."&deg;C</div>";
    echo "<div class='infobox_data'>Humidity: ".$row['HUMID']."%</div>";
    echo "<div class='infobox_time'>Captured: ".date("g:i:s a F j, Y ", strtotime($row["TIME"]))."</div>";
}

mysqli_close($con); ?>
```

Comment: `<meta refresh` :) or learn.jquery.com/ajax

Comment: jQuery AJAX is the easiest thing in the world :) 

Check it out. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: [`$.load();`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: Also, just FYI. Probably upgrade to use PDO for the connection. It's accepted practice.

Comment: @PatrickEaton what is PDO, please?

Comment: got it... PHP Data Objects!

Comment: It's more fun learning PDO. :D

Comment: Any chance you guys could help me out with the code? I'd really appreciate it, it will probably all click once I see it.

Answer (score 7):

Got it working, thanks for the help everyone.

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    loadstation();
});

function loadstation(){
    $("#station_data").load("station.php");
    setTimeout(loadstation, 2000);
}
```

**station.php**

```
<?php
include ("database.php");

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM sql347511.1 ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<div class='infobox_data' id='infobox_temp'>" . $row['TEMP'] . "&deg;C</div>";
    echo "<div class='infobox_data' id='infobox_humid'>" . $row['HUMID'] . "%</div>";
    echo "<div class='infobox_time'>At " . date("g:i:s a F j, Y ", strtotime($row["TIME"])) . "</div>";
    }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**Where to put the data**

```
<div id="station_data"></div>
```

Comment: This is a working solution. Did you test it on large scale model, did you try to run on multiple PC. I got on 20PC over a 3000 connection a my server CPU is getting 100% worikng

Answer (score 0):

You can make inputs from div on double click and then get this inputs value through jquery:

```
$().val;
```

then  using ajax send this value to php:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'url_to_php_which_update_mysql',
    data: {'data': 'value_from_input'},
    cache: false,
    success: function(response){
        $(input).val(response);
    }
});
```

And in php file you need to upload $_GET['data'] in Database

Comment: Thanks Masiama, any chance you could elaborate more on the code required?

Comment: How would I change or convert my existing code to make it work with the AJAX request?

Comment: @Sam Do you have textbox on page?

Comment: No, at the moment I'm just echoing the result into a <div> should I change it to an input and do it that way?

Comment: You need to gve unique id for every <div> and them you $('this_id').val(); to get value and then use ajax which is in my answer.