# How could i display Database in real time?

Tags: php, sql, database, stream, real-time

I want to display Database in HTML, but it does not update constantly when I change the data in the database, and i have to refreshing many times. Do you have any advice to optimize this ?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <?php
            while($result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            { 
                echo $result['temperature'];
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Search the web for `polling` and `caching`

Answer (score 0):

This is an open ended question and likely to attract opinions and controversy.  That being said, the technology you want is AJAX, or a JavaScript framework of some kind.

I would look into `vue.js`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Ajax to somehow check if the table has been updated and if it has pull the new data again. You will also need a timer to trigger the check.

I've found an answer that might help you:
[Live update MySQL Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24925579/live-update-mysql-data)